# Can a stationary distribution be zero vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

Suppose I have probabilities matrix between 3 states, for exampel we can take $P=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{9} & \frac{8}{9} & 0\\
0 & 0.3 & 0.7\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right)$, and we want to find the stationary probability. In order to do so we solve the equlation $wP=w$ where w is the vector of stationary distribution. Here $w=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$. Does it mean the matrix converges to a zero matrix? Does it have any special meaning ? can we make any consequences about the process (except there isn't any absorbing state of course)?

Answer (score 1):

Well first off probability matrices have rows that sum up to one. So your example is not a probability matrix. Markov chains are used to describe a physical process where a system evolves with time. If the zero vector is the solution, then the physical significance is that the "mass" completely escapes as time goes to infinite.

Comment: I fixed the matrix. Second, but it means that as time goes to infinity we won't be able to change state ? If so: on which state will we be stuck on?

Comment: Well i believe the w=(0,0,1) in the new matrix. However, to answer your other questions. Keep in mind it would be the limit as time goes to infinite. The limit can be zero. Realistically speaking though, the zero vector is a trivial solution that solves every wP=w equation. This is why, we ignore the zero vector as a solution.

Comment: The state space is finite hence the mass cannot escape.